# what is the meaning of competing alternatives

Tags: meaning

does it mean that in a company, for instance, the most probably hired interviewers left in the second round of testing? does it have to do with competent and still remaining . 
then if it is solved, can you guys give me some sentences to illustrate it?

Answer (score 1):

It means there are multiple courses of action, each of which presents some merits but none of which is (yet) clearly preferable. In this state, especially when the arguments for each option are evolving over time, it is as if the alternatives are in a competition to be selected.

> Managers are more prone to picking options fraught with high risk if they are forced to choose between competing alternatives, according to a new Canadian study. http://www.medindia.net/news/choosing-between-competing-alternatives-may-negatively-impact-decision-making-113535-1.htm
>
> An empirical example is provided using the process by which young women form their first conjugal residential union, with married and unmarried cohabitation representing the competing alternatives. http://www.psc.isr.umich.edu/pubs/abs/574

Answer (score 0):

It appears it is an expression used mainly in  *neuroscience* [competing
alternatives](http://cercor.oxfordjournals.org/content/15/11/1723.abstract):

> It has been widely argued that the left inferior frontal gyrus (LIFG) is involved in the control of retrieval of information from long-term memory. Recent claims that the LIFG is involved in selecting among semantic alternatives have been challenged on the grounds that the manipulation of selection demands may have been confounded with controlled retrieval.
>   ][1](http://cercor.oxfordjournals.org/content/15/11/1723.abstract)

[competing alternative behaviour](http://behavenet.com/competing-alternative-behaviors) :

> When one is trying to stop a bad habit, one can engage in a competing alternative behavior, which is an activity that inhibits the ability of the person with OCD to engage in the habit that s/he is trying to break. For example, if one is knitting, one is unable to simultaneously pull one's hair.